# Deploying a sails.js app via puppet fails on npm install

Tags: npm, puppet, sails.js

I'm deploying a sails.js app via puppet & here is my manifest:

```
class sails {
    include apt

    class { 'nodejs': 
        manage_repo => true,
    }

    vcsrepo { '/var/www':
      ensure   => latest,
      provider => git,
      source   => 'https://www.gitrepo.com',
      revision => 'master',
      require  => Class['nodejs'],
    } 

    exec { 'npm install':
        path    => '/usr/bin/',
        cwd     => '/var/www/',
        require => [Vcsrepo['/var/www'],Class['nodejs']],
    }
}
```

All goes well until the `npm install`, it gets through most dependencies, but then this happens:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/sails/Exec[npm install]/returns: npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws/-/ws-0.4.31.tgz 
Notice: /Stage[main]/sails/Exec[npm install]/returns: 
Notice: /Stage[main]/sails/Exec[npm install]/returns: > bson@0.1.8 install /var/www/node_modules/sails/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson 
Notice: /Stage[main]/sails/Exec[npm install]/returns: > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0) 
Notice: /Stage[main]/sails/Exec[npm install]/returns: 
Notice: /Stage[main]/sails/Exec[npm install]/returns: execvp(): No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on why this is?  If I run npm install manually in `/var/www` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem because I hadn't installed git.

Comment: Git is installed in my case

Comment: Then the only other thing I can suggest is to check the environment tres carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In the end I was able to fix it with:

```
sudo -i sh -c "cd ${app_directory}; npm install"
```

As per the discussion here:
https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/115#issuecomment-7386287